# Fortran equivalent of numpy.where() function?

Tags: numpy, fortran, slice

I would like to do something like this in [Fortran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran):

```
program where

real :: a(6) = (/ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 /)

print *, a(a>7)

end program
```

In [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) I would typically do this with [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) like this:

```py
import numpy

a = numpy.array([ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

print a[numpy.where(a>7)]

#or 

print a[a>7]
```

I've played around, but nothing has worked thus far, but I'm guessing it is fairly simple.

Comment: I removed the [tag:python] and [tag:numpy] tags because this is mostly a Fortran question, not a Python one.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I would argue for at least leaving numpy in, since it is partially implemented in Fortran, and those watching the tag may have valuable input here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll extend slightly the answer by @VladimirF as I suspect you don't want to limit yourself to the exact print example.

`a>7` returns a `logical` array corresponding to `a` with `.true.` at index where the condition is met, `.false.` otherwise.  The `pack` intrinsic takes such a mask and returns an array with those elements with `.true.` in the mask.

However, you can do other things with the mask which may fit under your `numpy.where` desire.  For example, there is the `where` construct (and `where` statement) and the `merge` intrinsic.  Further you can use `pack` again with the mask to get the indices and do more involved manipulations.

Comment: That's true, if you want to assign to such a subarray, you have to use `where`.

Comment: Also, with the `where` construct, you can use `elsewhere` to handle places where the condition is not met.

Answer (score 4):

```
program where

real :: a(6) = (/ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 /)

print *, pack(a,a>7)

end program
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find a related topic here: [Better way to mask a Fortran array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637105/better-way-to-mask-a-fortran-array)

I think both where and merge can do the task.

In python, **where** has the ability to assign different value according to the mask, for example

```
a = np.array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
b = np.where(a>7, 1, -1)
```

b will be array([-1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  1])

In Fortran, the equivalent of this is **merge**

```
real :: a(6) = (/ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 /)
real, allocatable :: b(:)
b = merge(1,-1,a>7)
print*, b
end
```

The MERGE function chooses alternative values based on the value of a mask. http://www.lahey.com/docs/lfpro78help/F95ARMERGEFn.htm

**where** can also do this, but it is slightly more complicated.

```
real :: a(6) = (/ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 /)
real, allocatable :: b(:)
b = a
where (a>7)
  b = 1
else where
  b = -1
end where
print*, b
end
```

a short version is this

```
b = a
b = -1
where (a>7) b = 1
```

You can find more information of where here: http://www.personal.psu.edu/jhm/f90/statements/where.html