# How to index an array with a mask in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I'm coming to Fortran from Python.

In Python / [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) I can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(5)
b = a*10

print b[a == 3]
#  Outputs: array([30])
```

In Fortran I have:

```
program test
implicit none

integer :: a(5)
integer :: b(5)
integer :: i

a = (/(i, i = 0, 4)/)
b = a*10

! I want to do this, but it doesn't work
!print *, b(a==3)

! So instead I do this...
do i=1,5
  if(a(i)==3) print*, b(i)
enddo

end
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this (for example, with intrinsic functions)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21435589/3157076

Comment: Thanks @francescalus . The question was subtly different but the answer provided is what I need. print *, pack(b,a==3) is what I was looking for.