# Better way to mask a Fortran array?

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, masking

I am wanting to mask a Fortran array. Here's the way I am currently doing it...

```
where (my_array <=15.0)
    mask_array = 1
elsewhere
    mask_array = 0
end where
```

So then I get my masked array with:

```
masked = my_array * mask_array
```

Is there a more concise way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the MERGE intrinsic function:

```
masked = my_array * merge(1,0,my_array<=15.0)
```

Comment: On the same theme `masked = MERGE(my_array, 0._blah, my_array<=15)`.

Answer (score 7):

Or, sticking with `where`,

```
masked = 0
where (my_array <=15.0) masked = my_array
```

I expect that there are differences, in speed and memory consumption, between the use of `where` and the use of `merge` but off the top of my head I don't know what they are.

Answer (score 5):

There are two different approaches already given here: one retaining [`where`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28645329/) and one using [`merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28637909/).  In the first, High Performance Mark mentions that there may be differences in speed and memory use (think about temporary arrays).  I'll point out another potential consideration (without making a value judgment).

```
subroutine work_with_masked_where(my_array)
  real, intent(in) :: my_array(:)
  real, allocatable :: masked(:)

  allocate(masked(SIZE(my_array)), source=0.)
  where (my_array <=15.0) masked = my_array
  ! ...
 end subroutine

subroutine work_with_masked_merge(my_array)
  real, intent(in) :: my_array(:)
  real, allocatable :: masked(:)

  masked = MERGE(my_array, 0., my_array<=15.)
  ! ...
end subroutine
```

That is, the `merge` solution can use automatic allocation.  Of course, there are times when one doesn't want this (such as when working with lots of `my_array`s of the same size: there are often overheads when checking array sizes in these cases): use `masked(:) = MERGE(...)` after handling the allocation (which may be relevant even for the question code).

Answer (score 0):

I find it useful to define a function `where` which takes an array of `logical`s and returns the `integer` indices of the `.true.` values, so e.g.

```
x = where([.true., .false., .false., .true.]) ! sets `x` to [1, 4].
```

This function can be defined as

```
function where(input) result(output)
  logical, intent(in) :: input(:)
  integer, allocatable :: output(:)
  
  integer :: i
  
  output = pack([(i, i=1, size(input))], input)
end function
```

With this `where` function, your problem can be solved as

```
my_array(where(my_array>15.0)) = 0
```

This is probably not the most performant way of doing this, but I think it is very readable and concise. This `where` function can also be more flexible than the `where` intrinsic, as it can be used e.g. for specific dimensions of multi-dimensional arrays.

**Limitations:**

Note however that (as @francescalus points out) this will not work for arrays which are not 1-indexed. This limitation cannot easily be avoided, as performing comparison operations on such arrays drops the indexing information, e.g.

```
real :: my_array(-2,2)
integer, allocatable :: indices(:)

my_array(-2:2) = [1,2,3,4,5]
indices = my_array>3
write(*,*) lbound(indices), ubound(indices) ! Prints "1 5".
```

For arrays which are not 1-indexed, in order to use this `where` function you would need the rather ugly

```
my_array(where(my_array>15.0)+lbound(my_array)-1) = 0
```

Comment: Afraid I'm very much against this: consider what happens when trying to use with the array `dimension my_array(-5:12)`. Also, WHERE constructs/statements are _much_ more flexible in general (I agree, for simple cases like of the question this won't matter).

Comment: @francescalus true. Personally, I don't use arrays which aren't 1-indexed, because I think it's too easy to drop the indexing. Also, could you give an example (aside from non-1-indexed arrays) where `where` constructs are more flexible than this `where` function?

Comment: (My) "flexible" was probably the wrong word, but `where (f(x)) x=g(y)` would seem to be clearer than the obvious rewritings with a `where` function. As a more general rule, I'd say that if you want to do masked assignment, use masked assignment rather than assignment with a vector subscript or assignment in a loop. (Which relates to a further concern I have: one uses this `where` function, finds it pretty neat, then one day decide to use `x(where(...))` in a place outside assignment where a vector subscript really isn't allowed/wise.)